# Issue with paypal smart buttons integration

Tags: javascript, paypal

I've already setup a paypal payments flow. In which if a user were to click to 'pay with PayPal', a pop up opens up which asks the user the sign in to their paypal account and then make the payment from there. This flow works as it is.
The issue I'm facing is with the 'pay with credit or debit card' button which the PayPal smart button JavaScript SDK provides. When clicking on this button, it does not open a pop up like it does for the 'pay with PayPal' button. Instead it opens an inline form.
I've seen sites where clicking on the 'pay with credit or debit card' button opens a pop up where the form is rendered.
What am I missing? I've gone through their Smart Buttons API docs and they have not mentioned how to switch between rendering things inline and a pop up.
This is the how I've configured the SDK:

```
paypal.Buttons({
    enableStandardCardFields: true,
    locale: 'en_US',
    commit: true,
    style: {
      label: 'pay',
      layout: 'vertical',
      fundingicons: 'true'
    },
    funding: {
      allowed: [ paypal.FUNDING.CARD ]
    },
    onInit: function(data, actions) {
      actions.enable()
    },
    createOrder: function() {
      $('div.loading-container').append('<h2>Processing your payment...</h2>')
      return fetch('/create_order', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
      }).then(function(data) {
        return data.table.id;
      });
    },
    onCancel: function(data) {
      $('div.loading-container').empty()
      return;
    },
    onApprove: function(data) {
      return fetch('/capture_order', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          orderID: data.orderID
        })
      }).then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
      }).then(function(details) {
        if (details.status == 400) {
          window.location.reload();
          return;
        }
        window.history.pushState({ urlPath:'/orders/thanks' }, "" , '/orders/thanks' );
        window.location.reload();
      })
    }
  }).render('div.paypal_container');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The black Debit or Credit Card button always renders inline (exception: a few countries it isn't enabled for). Most people want this, and consider it nice.

There's no way to make that black button open a window. You can disable the black button, leaving only the normal PayPal button, which has the other behavior.

Comment: But now, looks like even the black Debit/Credit Card button also open the pop-up, occasionally but not consistent, on the sandbox environment. But I prefer inline though. Can I make the inline rendering consistent even on sandbox?

Comment: Usually that would have to do with browser language/locale settings, sometimes the particular receiver account

Answer (score 2):

You can use this workaround to force the popup:

```
//Changes credit/debit button behavior to "old" version
onShippingChange: function(data,actions){
    //if not needed do nothing..
    return actions.resolve();
},
```

see also [Paypal Smart Payment buttons bug](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues/1224)

Comment: Stefan thank you so much for this! One quick question, does it have negative effects when I apply this workaround? I've read the documentation about onShippingChange and does not state that this will trigger to old version of CC form but actually solve my use case. What do you think.